# Why am I getting an 'Invalid Parameters' error when the generic type constraints are the same?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

In the code below, I am getting an error at 'action(u)', "Invalid Parameters", even though the type constraints on the generics are the same. Why is that and what can I do?

```
        public class Test<T> : IDoStuff where T : SampleA
        {

            Action<T> action;

            void DoStuff<U>(U u) where U : SampleA
            {
                action(u);
            }

        }
```

Comment: A `T` is a `SampleA`. A `U` is a `SampleA`. But that doesn't mean that a `U` is a `T`.

Comment: BTW, The following should work: `void DoStuff<U>(U u) where U : T`.

Comment: @DWright: Yes, but that expresses something slightly different (which is why it works).

Comment: @EricJ.: You are right, which is why I didn't offer it as an answer.  But it *might* suit OP's purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that SampleA represents animals, and you do this

```
public class Bird :  SampleA { }

public class Dog :  SampleA { }

Test<Bird> b = new Test<Bird>();
b.DoStuff<Dog>();
```

The field `action` now knows how to act on a Bird, but not on the Dog you passed it, even if they share an interface and common base class.

You can make this work by changing this line

```
Action<T> action;
```

to

```
Action<SampleA> action;
```

Comment: Good answer. Explained why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

`U` and `T` are not the same, even if they are derived from the same base class.